# MVVM Passing data from view to another view's viewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm new to MVVM and i am trying to pass a location data from my ContenView to DetailsView's viewModel which is DetailsViewViewModel.

My Opening View -> ContentView (My data is here)

Second View -> DetailsView

Data must be reach -> DetailsViewViewModel

Here is my sheet in ContentView

```
.sheet(item: $viewModel.selectedPlace) { place in
            DetailsView(location: place) { newLocation in
                viewModel.updateLocation(location: newLocation)
            }
```

I know i'm trying to send my data to details view and it's wrong. It was like that before i convert the architecture to the MVVM and this is the only place that i couldn't convert.
Also here is my DetailsViewViewModel

```
extension DetailsView {
@MainActor class DetailsViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum LoadingState {
        case loading, loaded, failed
    }
    var location: Location
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var description: String
    @Published var loadingState = LoadingState.loading
    @Published var pages = [Page]()
    init() {
        self.location =  // ??? how should i initialize?
        self.name = location.name
        self.description = location.description
    }
```

What is the proper way to this. Using another views data in another views viewmodel.

Comment: You should either inject the view model, something like `DetailsView(viewModel: DetailsViewViewModel(location: place))`  or create it in the detail view init in a similar manner

Comment: It doesn't work because compiler says 
"Cannot find 'DetailsViewViewModel' in scope"

Comment: Well it's an inner class inside the view so you need to call it correctly. I assumed you did know your own code well enough to fix that yourself. Try to change it to `DetailsView. DetailsViewViewModel` and you of course need to change the init as well.

Comment: I forgot it was inside extension. It worked. Thank you for that simple and clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to put in an example that uses the convenience of `@EnvironmentObject`:

1. Your view model is a class that conforms to `ObservableObject`, so you can have those nice variables `@Published` that change the state of the views.
2. Your main view - or also your `App` - must "own" the view model, meaning it needs to create the one and only instance of your view model that will be used by all views.
3. You pass the view model from one view to another using `@StateObject` and `@ObservableObject`, but in this example I prefer to use another approach. Make your main view inject the *instance* of your view model in the environment, so all other views will read from that. The main view uses `.environmentObject(viewModel)` to do that.
4. The other views read the view model from the environment by calling `@EnvironmentObject`. They create a variable specifying *only the type* - there can only be one instance per type in the environment.

This is the way with which all view will read from the same model. See below a functioning example:

Step 1:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var color: Color = .blue
    
    @Published var showSheet = false
    
    func changeColorTo(_ color: Color) {
        self.color  = color
    }
    
}
```

Steps 2 and 3:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MyViewModel()   // Here is the step (2)
    
    var body: some View {
        OneView()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)    // Here is the step (3)
    }
}
```

Step 4 in two different views:

```
struct OneView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel    // Here is step (4)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current color")
                .padding()
                .background(viewModel.color)
            
            Button {
                if viewModel.color == .blue {
                    viewModel.changeColorTo(.yellow)
                } else {
                    viewModel.changeColorTo(.blue)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Change color")
            }

            Button {
                viewModel.showSheet.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Now, show a sheet")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showSheet) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel    // Here is step (4)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The sheet is showing")
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                viewModel.showSheet.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Now, stop showing the sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying, I realize that its much more easier to do it by using @EnvironmentObject instead of passing data. Thanks!

Comment: Why would the views share the same view model? Shouldn't each view have its own view model?

Comment: The view model accesses the model/ data so your views don’t have to do it directly; this is a way to separate the roles that makes the code more scalable. Because different views may need to access the same set of data (for example, you can have one blackjack game but different views showing the board, the score or your cards), you can share the same view model. You can pass it, either as a parameter to the next view, or using @EnvironmentObject.

Comment: nice, and here i was thinking of passing data between views through bindings etc, this is much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

since location data is your business layer data, you need a use-case to provide it to both view models, and to optimize it caching the response is the way to go.

-ViewModel is responsible to hold the latest view states and data

-The domain layer is responsible to handle business logic

-The data layer (networking, cache, persistence, or in-memory) is responsible for providing the most efficient data storage/retrieval solutions

So, if you are okay with these defenitions and think of writing test for these view models you know that it is not right to inject data from another ViewModel because you would not test that view model on making sure it passes the data to the next viewModel and it is not its responsibility, but you write many tests for you data layer to make sure service calls and caching systems are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise DetailsViewModel from ContentView sheet when you are adding the DetailsView like below:

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .sheet(item: $vm.selectedPlace,
                   onDismiss: didDismiss) {newLocation in
                //Here Initialise the DetailViewModel with a location
                DetailsView(detailsVM: DetailsViewModel(location: newLocation))
            }

    }
    
    func didDismiss(){
        
    }
}
```

DetailsView:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    @StateObject var detailsVM : DetailsViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the DetailesView")
    }
}
```

DetailsViewModel:

```
class DetailsViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var location:Location
    init(location:Location){
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

struct ParentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
            Text("btn")
        })
            .sheet(item: $viewModel.selectedPlace) { place in
                DetailView(name: place.name,
                           location: place.location,
                           description: place.description)
            }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var description: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(location)
            Text(description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My detailsview doesn't have name, location, description paremeters.  The parameters are in the viewModel not in the view. I'm trying to send the data to detailsview's viewmodel not itself.

Comment: Did you try the environment object operator? this is one of the latest MVVM tutorials I find very useful  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b55npVkqa5U

Comment: Thank you, i will check it out later but i don't think it is related with MVVM architecture.